# What is the difference between пока and ещё?

Tags: словоупотребление

the difference in these two words is something I don't understand, is it just me or do those words actually mean the same thing?

for example: if I want to say

> I don't Know yet!

do I say

> пока не знаю

or

> ещё не знаю

??

Answer (score 6):

In the context you are using it, the words indeed have a similar meaning - "yet". Fun fact, you can also say:

> Пока еще не знаю.

*Пока* in the meaning of *yet* is actually the short of *пока еще*. From [Ushakov's dictionary](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1101150):

> ПОКА́
>   нареч.
>
> ...
>   *со словом* “еще” или *без него*. До сего времени, до этих пор, всё еще. *Сведений пока нет. Пока еще ждем. Пока еще не уехали.*

Answer (score 6):

They're really similar (and can be used together as the previous poster suggested), but intuitively, I'd say **Я ещё не знаю** implies a greater degree of confidence, imminence, and/or proximity in time, compared to **Я пока не знаю**, of your knowing eventually. You could say that **пока** is neutral expectation-wise, while **ещё** is somewhat on the optimistic side.

Come to think of it, the latter is a better way to describe it, because with *undesirable* eventualities, the confidence factor is reversed: **Я ещё не умер** is definitely upbeat compared to the resigned-ish **Я пока не умер.**

On *third* thoughts (sorry but I'm really making these little discoveries as I go along, it's fascinating), the very neutrality of **пока** can, with these undesirable outcomes, give it a "so far so good" touch that doesn't quite work with **ещё**. E.g. **Съел-таки** *(=я всё-таки съел)* **эти просроченные консервы. Пока не умер.**

So in the end, what I could definitely say is that **ещё** is about a more likely, or temporally nearer, outcome — which is consistent with its being more "optimistic" because when it's not about being "almost there", it's about defying the odds.

Comment: @ Nikolay Ershov  пока is "for now"; across this lump of space-time" it implies movement in time. ещё is "still"; at this very moment in space and time; it doesn't imply movement in time.

Я пока не умер— For now (at present) I'm not dead (but who knows about the future). Я ещё не умер— I'm still not dead. (and we're not going to think about the future at all; it only matter in this moment.